# Pandas: apply function that return multiple new columns over Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to speed up the code implementation below and improve the performance, as I am working with a dataframe with 40k columns. And I need to apply the following function to all the columns of the dataframe.

```
def differencing(col,per=1):
    df[f'{col}_d{per}'] = df[col].diff(periods = per)
    df[f'{col}_d{per}'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
    df[f'{col}_d{per}_ind'] = np.where(df[f'{col}_d{per}'] > 0 , 1, np.where(df[f'{col}_d{per}'] < 0, -1,0)) # 3 classes


for col in df.columns:
    differencing(col,per=1)
```

I only know how to use a for loop to apply this function column by column. How can I speed this up ? Problem with apply is that the function is adding 2 new columns to the existing dataframe. This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much all you do can be done directly on the dataframe, instead of per-series and iterating on the columns:

```
def differencing(df, per=1):
    dif = df.diff(periods=per).fillna(0).add_suffix(f'_per{per}')
    ind = np.sign(dif).add_suffix('_ind')
    return df.join([dif, ind])

differencing(df)
```

That’s roughly a 50% reduction in duration on a 5-column 10_000-rows dataframe. On a 5000-column 10-rows dataframe this reduced the time from 24 seconds to 0.016 seconds (caveat: both measured on my machine which runs a lot of other things simultaneously though).

Comment: instead of `(dif.gt(0).astype(int) - dif.lt(0).astype(int))`, wouldn't `np.sign(dif).astype('int').add_suffix('_ind')` be faster ?

Comment: That is indeed even faster @user1769197, I’ll update it.

Comment: @user1769197  You were telling another solution provider to follow my solution idea of using `np.sign`.  Would you give credit to my original idea by upvoting my answer?

Comment: @user1769197  It's my solution that you neither accepted nor upvoted.  The one below.  Not this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can fine-tune your code to speed it up by:

1. Replace the nested `np.where` to determine signs of values by using the [`numpy.sign()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) function
2. Combine the first 2 statements into one

```
def differencing(col,per=1):
    df[f'{col}_d{per}'] = df[col].diff(periods = per).fillna(0)
    df[f'{col}_d{per}_ind'] = np.sign(df[f'{col}_d{per}']).astype(int)

for col in df.columns:
    differencing(col,per=1)
```